# iterator type for lists

Tags: c++

I know that `vector<double>::iterator` returns **random access iterator** type.What is the iterator type returned by `list<double>::iterator`.Is it a **bi-directional iterator**?

Comment: Just a point on decorum. If you had googled "list iterator bi-directional" you would have found what you needed. Thats probably why you're being downvoted.

Comment: `vector<double>::iterator` is a *type*, not a function. It doesn't return anything. Also, do you mean a "random access iterator" or a "random-access iterator"? I like my iterators to be deterministic...

Comment: Also, from a [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list): `iterator BidirectionalIterator`. Seeing that listed under **member types** sort of clears up Kerrek's point as well.

Comment: Yeah i googled it.I turn to stack flow only when i don't get answers from google.What it was mentioned there in several google searches was that the list container meets bi-directional,forward,input and output iterator requirements.I specifically need to know which iterator type it is .Anyway i got my question answered.Thnx.

Comment: question doesn't make sense.Checkout my own answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's `bidirectional iterator`.

n3337 23.3.5.1/1

**A list is a sequence container that supports bidirectional iterators**

Answer (score 3):

It's bidirectional because you can still use ++ and -- on it. if you can only do ++ it's a forward iterator (see std::forward_list).

Comment: :)) Well, I'd say you can use ++ and -- *because* it's bidirectional, not the other way around...

Comment: Hrm I suppose. I think either way it's stated is pretty clear though.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I would state it the way bstamour stated it.  bi-directional iterator is a concept.  If an iterator meets the requirements of the bi-directional iterator concept, then it is a bi-directional iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,most of my question itself is wrong.I understood it after a long study of C++ reference.Since my question doesn't make much sense,I'm gonna answer it myself.`vector<double>::iterator` returning something makes no sense.Its a **type**.C++ standard library makes heavy use of typedefs in classes to alias other types.

So `vector<double>:iterator` is a type.To be more precise it is an alias (using typedef).And that alias in the case of `vector<double>::iterator` is to a `random-access Iterator` type.In case of `list<double>::iterator`, `iterator` is an alias to `bi-directional` type iterator.

This is also analogous to `vector<double>::size_type` where `size_type` is a type which is an alias to `size_t` type

i.e `typedef size_t  size_type` is present in `vector<double>` class.

If you find any misconceptions or mistakes.Please Clarify.